# Fitnesse & XPath - Count() does not return an integer, returns the list instead

Tags: xpath, fitnesse-slim, browser-testing

When using Fitnesse, Slim and the Browser Testing framework I was given the challenge to count the amount of items within an ordered list (simplified):

```
<a>
    <b>1</b>
    <b>2</b>
    <b>3</b>
</a>
```

I found that one of the counting methods:

`|check |number of items |xpath=//b    |in |xpath=//a |3 |`

does not work since it would only test for the number of times **text** appears upon a webpage, not the element. Thus I was pointed to the counting function of xpath but that returns the *list* of items instead of the total amount of occurrences, as seen below:

```
|check |value of        |xpath=//ol[count(li)=3] |[<b>1</b>
                                                   <b>2</b>
                                                   <b>3</b>] expected: [3] |
```

As such, how would I be able to get an integer of the count of occurrences of a certain element?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the entire xpath with  <kbd>count</kbd> as shown below.

Considered `ol` with `class="nav-links" for the below explanation.

```
count(//ol[@class='nav-links']/li)
```

Checking the number of `li` under the above said `ol` in chrome <kbd>Elements</kbd> tab.

Note: you don't get any output if you try `count(xpath)` in `Elements` tab.
[image: Count from Chrome Elements Tab]

To see the count just tested the xpath in the chrome <kbd>Console</kbd> tab.
[image: Count from Chrome Elements Tab]